# How to handle double entry check java script prompt using selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, testing, webdriver

any one help me out, 
scenario: need to fill the double entry check prompt/alert
This prompt/alert has two text boxes.. need to fill these two and click on OK button.

Tried solutions:

1. Switch to the prompt/alert using `Alert alert1=driver.switchTo().alert();`
   with out any error able to switch to alert. but unable to locate textboxes.
2. This prompt looks like window.. but by using `getWindowHandles()` is not giving any of window code to this prompt.. so it mayn't be a window..

Thanks,
sateesh.k

Comment: Could you show us some code of your solutions?

Comment: solution 1 tried:if(CommonUtilities.isAlertPresent()){
    System.out.println("prompt present");
    
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Alert alert2=driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert2.accept();    // im able to switch to alert but im unable to accept alert.

Comment: solution 2 tried : if(CommonUtilities.isAlertPresent()){
    System.out.println("prompt present");
    
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Alert alert2=driver.switchTo().alert();
         
    WebElement panNoTB = CommonUtilities.waitTillElementLocated(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input"));
    
     panNoTB.sendKeys("abc123");         // this giving exception like element not found

Comment: solution 3 tried: if(CommonUtilities.isAlertPresent()){
    System.out.println("prompt present");
    
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Alert alert2=driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert2.accept();     
    driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("ABCDE1234F"); // no exception shown but not filled any in any text box..

Comment: add those in [question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32836321/edit)

Comment: A JavaScript alert box with multiple text fields is not possible.  Are you in actual fact seeing a basic auth dialogue (like http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Selenium sel = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl());

sel.answerOnNextPrompt("text1");
sel.keyPress("id=''", "\\13");
//or
sel.keyPressNative("\n");
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("text2");
```

Comment: sel.answerOnNextPrompt("text1");
sel.keyPress("id=''", "\\13");      tried this solution but facing  exception like .......java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: answerOnNextPrompt

Comment: sel.keyPressNative("\n");
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("text2");                                  for this code facing exception like                                                           java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "

Answer (score 0):

There is [sendKeys](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#sendKeys(java.lang.String)) method available in Alert interface.

Have you tried with this ?

```
Alert alert1=driver.switchTo().alert();
alert1.sendKeys("Hello");
alert1.accept();
```